# Cordova ionic app not working on Android 9 && 10

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-9.0-pie, android-10.0

My ionic application not working on android 9 devices, works perfectly fine on android device with version less than 9.
Application doesn’t connect to backend upon loading the landing page.
Any ideas ?

Environment I am using :
Ionic:

ionic (Ionic CLI) : ^5.0.0 
Angular ^7.2.2

Cordova:

cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0

System:

Android SDK Tools : 29
NodeJS : v10
npm : 6.2.0

Comment: what errors or logs can you share? otherwise unclear how to help you;/

Comment: You are using http request for your backend and not https

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Reason

This is due to this policy starting in Android 9 : https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config.html#CleartextTrafficPermitted

> Applications intending to connect to destinations using only secure connections can opt-out of supporting cleartext (using the unencrypted HTTP protocol instead of HTTPS) to those destinations.
>
> Note: The guidance in this section applies only to apps that target Android 8.1 (API level 27) or lower. Starting with Android 9 (API level 28), cleartext support is disabled by default.

Cleartext (HTTP traffic) is now disabled by default, so it amounts to having something like this

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
  <domain includeSubdomains="true">*</domain>
</domain-config>
```

### Solution

Replace all http calls with https URLs.

Or...

#### Force HTTP (not secure)

If you really need to allow HTTP traffic for some requests, you can do so by adding some config in your Android Manifest, or create a plugin to update the manifest every time you rebuild the app from scratch.

You need to add an attribute to the `<application>` tag in the manifest, so to not overwrite everything, you need to use the `<edit-config>` tag with `mode="merge"` (see: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#edit-config )

*HTTP is not considered a secure protocol, and every request sent (and its payload) can be read by an attacker, so be careful*

`plugin.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        id="phonegap-plugin-old-http-support-android" version="0.0.1">
    <name>OldHttpSupportPlugin</name>

    <description>Force HTTP for Android 9+</description>
    <license>MIT</license>

    <keywords>cordova,android,http</keywords>
  
    <engines>
        <engine name="cordova" version=">=6.0.0"/>
        <engine name="cordova-android" version=">=7.0.0"/>
    </engines>
  

    <platform name="android">
        <config-file target="res/xml/config.xml" parent="/*">
            <feature name="OldHttpSupportPlugin">
                <param name="android-package" value="YOUR.PACKAGE.plugin.OldHttpSupportPlugin"/>
            </feature>
        </config-file>


        <!-- Source file for Android -->
        <source-file src="src/android/network_security_config.xml" target-dir="res/xml/" />

        <edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" target="/manifest/application" mode="merge">
            <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
    </platform>
</plugin>
```

`network_security_config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">my.domain.com</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">example.org</domain>
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">111.222.333.444</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add in config.xml inside android platform section the following:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Final result:

```
<platform name="android">
...
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
...
</platform>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem with `Ionic 3 and Cordova Android 9.0`

I solved it by putting these lines in `config.xml` file. My solution was a little bit different than [@Emilio's Ferrer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6888377/emilio-ferrer) solution

First you need to add `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"`in the `<widget>` target on the file begining. Without this setting, you won't be able to build your app.

Your `<widget>`target will look like this.

```
<widget id="your.id" version="x.x.x" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
```

Then add this inside the `<platform name="android"` tag

```
<edit-config src="platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" target="AndroidManifest.xml">
        <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Note that this is a workaround to allow requests over HTTP, and of course it is recommended that you make requests only to addresses under SSL certificate.